# Can you change at which level of the Spawn Area people spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

i.e. the bottom floor. I want to make a cool tower that goes up to y65 then you can join the world.

But, I need people that come into the world to spawn at the bottom of the spawn area. Possibly by using a command block that people would use a button and teleport them to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way Minecraft handles player spawning, they will always (naturally) spawn on the highest block that isn´t water, like the normal y=64 of typical worlds. You could get everyone on the server, then run `/spawnpoint @a`  for everyone, but it wont affect new players who come on later. I´d put a barrier platform at y=255 and a command block chain saying `/spawnpoint @a[radius=5] ~ (y level) ~`  and then `/tp @a[radius=5] ~ (y level) ~ .` this will teleport all new players to the spawnpoint you select.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `@a[distance=..5]`